# how to pass value from one php page to another using session

Tags: php, session, post

I can pass values form one page to another but I need to pass value like this,

Page 1:

Page4.php

Page3.php

I need to pass the value in a text field in the Page1.php to a text field in Page2.php, since the form is not directly redirectly to page2, I am unable to pass the value, I tried session, form post method and few other methods but I am yet to succeed.

I would be very happy if you can help me with the code or some suggestions.

Thanks!

Edit..........

I found the answer, thanks for the help, it was actually a careless mistake on my part, I used $_post instead of $_session.

Its working now.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Showing us your code would be a good start.

Comment: It can be a little confusing if you don't know the order of events.  A page's PHP code gets executed, *then* the page loads.  If you load a new page using a form, the form's input tags will be available in the PHP code of the next page under $_REQUEST.  From there, you can add to $_SESSION or simply assign to form values on the new page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use something like this:

page1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['myValue']=3; // You can set the value however you like.
?>
```

Any other PHP page:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['myValue'];
?>
```

A few notes to keep in mind though: You need to call `session_start()` BEFORE any output, HTML, echos - even whitespace.

You can keep changing the value in the session - but it will *only* be able to be used after the first page - meaning if you set it in page 1, you will not be able to use it until you get to another page or refresh the page.

The setting of the variable itself can be done in one of a number of ways:

```
$_SESSION['myValue']=1;
$_SESSION['myValue']=$var;
$_SESSION['myValue']=$_GET['YourFormElement'];
```

And if you want to check if the variable is set before getting a potential error, use something like this:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['myValue'])
{
    echo $_SESSION['myValue'];
}
else
{
    echo "Session not set yet.";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Solution using just POST - no $_SESSION

page1.php

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
    <textarea name="textarea1" id="textarea1"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
    // this page outputs the contents of the textarea if posted
    $textarea1 = ""; // set var to avoid errors
    if(isset($_POST['textarea1'])){
        $textarea1 = $_POST['textarea1']
    }
?>
<textarea><?php echo $textarea1;?></textarea>
```

---

Solution using $_SESSION and POST

page1.php

```
<?php

    session_start(); // needs to be before anything else on page to use $_SESSION
    $textarea1 = "";
    if(isset($_POST['textarea1'])){
        $_SESSION['textarea1'] = $_POST['textarea1'];
    }

?>


<form action="page1.php" method="post">
    <textarea name="textarea1" id="textarea1"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<br /><br />
<a href="page2.php">Go to page2</a>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
    session_start(); // needs to be before anything else on page to use $_SESSION
    // this page outputs the textarea1 from the session IF it exists
    $textarea1 = ""; // set var to avoid errors
    if(isset($_SESSION['textarea1'])){
        $textarea1 = $_SESSION['textarea1']
    }
?>
<textarea><?php echo $textarea1;?></textarea>
```

---

WARNING!!! - This contains no validation!!!

Comment: better to use hidden fields. <input type="hidden" id="hidden-id" value="your value to pass" />