# How to store POST values in SESSION and use it on another page PHP

Tags: php, session, post, null

I have a little newbie question. I've couldn't find proper answer to this, so I have to try here..

Well, I have 2 pages, each one with form on it.
1st page has simple, enter your username, than I want to process it to 2nd one
Problem is, when I submit form on 1st page, it seems like it doesn't store my POST data from it, and giving me null value on second page, or empty..
What Ive done so far is..
1st page

```
<?php 
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $_SESSION['username']=$_POST['username'];
}
else{
    $username='';
}


 ?>
```

and form:

```
<form class="" method="POST" action="combo.php">
                        <label for="username">Enter your username</label>
                        <input type="text" name="username">
                        <?php 
                        print_r($_SESSION); ?>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Start!">
                    </form>
```

On second page, when I var_dump('$_SESSION') it gives me a NULL value, so it seems like it isn't stored it from first page.

Can someone please explain what Im doing wrong. Note, on both pages first thing in code is session_start();

Thanks

Comment: you need `session_start();` on your form page.

Comment: Yes, there are on both pages as well

Comment: Are you sure you are not sending out some output before calling `session_start()` somewhere? Turn on error reporting and see what error you get.

Comment: in else part, it should be `$_SESSION['username']` not `$username`

Comment: Yes error reporting is set to E_ALL in php.ini, I've added in my script just for case.. and.. no errors are returned

Comment: Also if the class property is going to be empty, you don't need to have it.

Comment: *On second page, when I var_dump('$_SESSION')* - You are doing it wrong. It should be `var_dump` without the single quotes.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju So if I set:
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $_SESSION['username']=$_POST['username'];

}
else {
 $_SESSION['username']="";
}
On 2nd page var_dump outputs:
["username"]=>
  string(0) ""

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to pass value from one php page to another using session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598133/how-to-pass-value-from-one-php-page-to-another-using-session)

Comment: check if the post value is coming to your page where you r setting session.

Comment: When I try  to give 'fixed' val to session on first page, like $_SESSION['user]="myUsername" It works correctly on 2nd page, var_dump outputs that session val. But when I want to store POST val in session it doesn't works.. I have no idea what to do next

Comment: After press submit button print $_POST['username']  and check username set or not

Comment: Put id attribute in input.<input type="submit" id="username" name="username">